# No se realizan los cambios en mi plantilla luego de editar el css.min con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Quisiera que me ayuden con un pequeñito problema que tengo, bueno es que me baje una plantilla con html5 que usa **bootstrap** , pero mi problema es que al editar el archivo **css.min** para modificar algunos detalles,se realiza el cambio lo observo en navegador al momento de guardar, pero cierro el navegador cargo de nuevo la pagina que la modifique pero sigue sin hacerse los cambios.Estoy trabajando de manera local. con xampp editor de texto sublime text.
Espero haber sido un poco mas especifico.
Tal vez alguien que me pueda ayudar con mi problema cual seria la solución. Gracias.
Si estoy haciendo mal las cosas ayudarme estoy empezando colegas.
[image: En el siguiente archivo lo estoy modificando.]

Comment: ¿Cómo haces los cambios en el CSS?¿Dónde/Cómo está alojada tu página? A esta pregunta le faltan datos para saber cuál  es la causa del problema.

Comment: Amigo ya ingrese mas detalles a mi pregunta espero me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dices, y sin más datos, creo que pueden estar pasando dos cosas.

- La primera es que estés modificando el css.min sobre la consola de
  desarrollador del propio navegador y por lo tanto no se almacenen los
  cambios en el fichero original, esto explicaría que al recargar la
  pagina desaparecieran los cambios.
- La segunda causa que se me ocurre es que estés modificando el fichero
  original de estilos correctamente, pero que sea el propio navegador
  el que cachee la hoja de estilos que carga.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que en el codigo tienes enlazada la misma hoja de estilos que estas editando. En bootstrap suelen venir la bootstrap.css y la bootstrap.min.css (minimizada)

Answer (score 0):

Yo he sufrido mucho este tipo de cosas con la caché del navegador. Hace cosas rarísimas como que por más que pulses refrescar no refresca los ficheros.

Lo mejor es asegurarte como ya te han dicho que realmente estés cargando la hoja de estilos correcta, activa el modo desarrollador de Google Chrome y activa desactivar la caché...

Te adjunto captura..

[image: Desactivar caché en Google Chrome]